# How do I go about restoring an SSAS 2000 .CAB file using 2008 tools?

Tags: database, ssas, mdx, restore, business-intelligence

I am trying to work out through the sample code that comes with Fast Track to MDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post where Darren Gosbell (SSAS MVP) has upgraded Foodmart 2000 SSAS DB to 2005 (which is by and large identical format as 2008).  There are a few issues he mentions that you have to be aware of since SSAS 2000 and SSAS 2005/8 are architecturally quite different.

[http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/04/02/UpgFoodmart2000.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815115303/http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2006/04/02/upgfoodmart2000.aspx)

Also, be sure to read the comments.  The link in the original post doesn't work but he has posted the file to his skydrive and referenced that location in a reply to a comment.

HTH,
-rp